# WKWebView popup is not working in MacOS app

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I have WKWebView in my MacOS app. The URL I am using in it has a model popup on preview button click. But whenever I am clicking on Preview button, nothing happens. I tried adding below preferences code but no luck.

```
   let preferences = WKPreferences()
   preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
   preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: You won't be able to tap few links on the WebSite, because they would be HTTP instead of HTTPS. WKWebView by default blocks all HTTP requests which aren't secure.**

To bypass, just add NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads as true in info.plist file.

```swift
override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    webView?.uiDelegate = self
    webView?.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

func webView(_: WKWebView, createWebViewWith _: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures _: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? {
    self.webView?.load(navigationAction.request)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I tried this delegate method but ```navigationAction.request.url```  is nil.

Comment: I have update my answer check it